# Get text from TextView and copy it to clipboard in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, copy-paste

I want to copy value inside textview by clicking to icon. This is what I've done so far:

```js
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{marginTop: 50, marginLeft: 50}}>
              <View>
                 <Text>Логин:</Text>
                 <Text ref='myText'>45645546654</Text>    
              </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Clipboard.setString(this.refs.myText.props.children)}>
              <View>
                <MaterialIcons 
                   name='content-copy' 
                   size={21} 
                 />
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
  }
```

Workspace: https://snack.expo.io/@jasurkurbanov/updated2

It is somewhat working on snack. But what when I am running it on my phone I am getting error.

***Undefinied is not an object ('evaluating '_this.refs.myText.props.children')***

Answer (score 0):

You should defined your refs variable on `constructor()`.

for example:

```
constructor() {
...
    this.textViewRefs = React.createRef();
...
}

render() {
    return (
...
        <Text ref={this.textViewRefs}>45645546654</Text>
...
    )
}
```

look this https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html for further information